# Configuration page for newly installed SparkPost extension error: Cannot decrypt token. Invalid format

Tags: drupal, extension, sparkpost

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
> moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
> with more details about what action you were performing when this
> occurred. Cannot decrypt token. Invalid format. Return to home page.

I have installed the SparkPost extension for CiviCRM 5.39.0 on Drupal 7.82. I have ensured that the installation steps 1, 2 and 3 here are complete. When attempting to follow step four, going to Administer > System Settings > Outgoing mail (SparkPost) I receive the above error on the screen.

I have cleared caches and double-checked paths.

Google search shows exactly one post with this verbiage but I am not able to figure out the relationship between that one issue and this: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2563. It only comes up here as part of the exceptions thrown verbiage in the codebase.

Note: I am working on getting CiviCRM updated, but since CiviSMTP is kaput by Aug 1, 2022, I was hoping that updating CiviCRM was not the solution.

Please let me know what else I can try, thank you!

```
    Jul 31 22:09:44  [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Cannot decrypt token. Invalid format."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => Civi\Crypto\Exception\CryptoException {#1368
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "Cannot decrypt token. Invalid format."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/Crypto/CryptoToken.php"
    #line: 206
    trace: {
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/Crypto/CryptoToken.php:206 {
        ›   default:
        ›     throw new CryptoException("Cannot decrypt token. Invalid format.");
        › }
      }
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/Crypto/CryptoToken.php:141 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/CRM/Sparkpost.php:54 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Sparkpost.php:64 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:644 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php:76 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:352 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php:98 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:286 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:458 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/includes/menu.inc:527 { …}
      /var/www/html/fosterclub/docroot/index.php:21 { …}
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I found this reported issue, which may be the same: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost/-/issues/110

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the OP, and tried the answer below and it didn't work.

Comment: This may not be helpful, other than offering hope, but we needed to switch client to SparkPost. D7, civi 5.49.x, SparkPost 1.5. We succeeded with no problems relating to tokens. If i can help in anyway then happy to try.

Comment: wild guess but might php version be a possible factor

Comment: I am using PHP 7.2 but will consider going to 7.3 or 7.4 if that helps. I ended up implementing SendGrid because the prices are similar enough and it worked out of the box, so I will likely not switch back unless some other reasoning comes up.

Comment: Hope SendGrid works for you. We tried shifting same client to SG a couple of years back and the outcome was bad due to many spammers using same IP pool and SG did nothing to help resolve. So far, cross fingers, the SP experience has been better.

Comment: Yeah, I already am seeing some of my mailings go to spam :( It would be wonderful if I could somehow resolve the above issue. Will keep posting back. Someone on the issue thread above said they were on 7.4 and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Install from git. The sparkpost-1.5.tar.gz was released after fixes for this were committed in July, but for some reason aren't in the release.

Answer (score 1):

It might also be that your crypto keys in civicrm.settings.php aren't using a valid format. The docs are a bit difficult to follow to figure out how to generate a proper key. You can use this tool: https://civisettings.symbiotic.coop

Note you need to REPLACE the existing lines for CRED_KEYS and SIGN_KEYS in civicrm.settings.php with the output, not add more lines to the file at the end, since then the existing lines will still get used.

You may also need to clear out any existing api key and re-enter it on the admin page to get it re-encrypted. You can delete it in mysql directly with `delete from civicrm_setting where name='sparkpost_apiKey';`

Also make sure you are using the latest version of sparkpost - note there were some changes added last week related to crypto.

Comment: I updated the file with the code in the tool, was that what I was supposed to do? It didn't fix the issue, after also rebuilding caches and permissions, etc.

Comment: I have tried adding these settings to my civicrm.settings.php file and it has not resolved the above issue.

Comment: Ok it's possible there's an issue in the extension, but I'll update the answer with a couple more things.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: a few comments. our first sparkpost set up went fine. our second one hit this token issue. i wondered if we had done something different, eg using cv en on the latter but not on the first, since i noticed that the row in civicrm_settings had no 'created id'. so i disabled via cv. then enabled via UI. no difference. I then uninstalled via UI at which point the com.cividesk.email.sparkpost:version row in db still existed, but now had a created_id of my contact. i triend enabling via UI again. same issue

Comment: i then tried editing the civicrm.settings.php - no improvement. i await my technical colleague joining in this hunt tomorrow. Note, this is a much older site. is on same civi version now, but has been around for > 10 years (just in case that is part of the puzzle)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the fix for this is in git, but is not in the zip even though v1.5 was tagged after fixes were applied for some reason isn't in the sparkpost-1.5.tar.gz

Suggest "git clone git@lab.civicrm.org:extensions/sparkpost.git". Then delete the .git folder in the sparkpost extension directory as you probably don't want to keep that.